# Access a directory using its alias

Tags: alias

I have created an alias for a path that I use often like that:

`alias example='/home/user/directory/'`

(in the `home/.bash_aliases`)

The problem is that I want to access that directory via terminal like:

`example/file`

but it doesn't work.

This is the first time that I try to create an alias and I think that I am missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `alias` is a shorthand for a command or something that ultimately evaluates to a command. It cannot be used like a *variable*, which can be used as anything, but has specific syntax. For example, the following creates a variable and uses it:

```
example='/home/user/directory/'
ls "$example"/file
```

A variable is evaluated using `$`. Always remember to enclose your variables in quotes (`""`) - this helps prevent against unexpected results when your variable contains spaces or special characters, like `*`.

Comment: Thank you, if I want to use it as a variable in which file should I add the definition?

Comment: @Adam `.bashrc` should do fine.