# How can I set a shortcut to my Windows folder in WSL/Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My school homework files are on the Windows file system at `/mnt/c/Users/nyck33/Documents`, and it's a hassle to `cd ../..` from home then `cd mnt/c/Users/nyck33/Documents` each time.

How can I set a shortcut so I can cd to that Windows file system from home (which means I can skip the `cd ../..` which takes me to root).

Or if that is not possible at least from root after I `cd ../..`

Comment: You can always do something like in https://askubuntu.com/questions/613079/access-a-directory-using-its-alias where you could set `homework=/mnt/c/Users/nyck33/Documents` then accessing it by typing in `cd $homework` to take you right there.  You can always add the `homework=` line to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: @Terrance that worked perfectly, thanks but with quotations around the path in `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities, but in all cases, keep in mind that accessing files on the Windows drive from WSL/Ubuntu is *drastically* slower than having them in the virtual ext4 filesystem.  If you experience performance issues, consider moving the files into your Ubuntu home directory (`~`).

Also, there's no need to `cd ../..` from your home directory.  Just start the path with `/`, as in `cd /mnt/c/Users/nyck33` to make it an absolute path rather than a relative one.  Do this at least once "manually" in order to make it repeatable using some of the history-search options below.

With that in mind, here are a few (perhaps too many) ways to simplify access to your Windows Documents directory from inside WSL/Ubuntu.  My recommendation is the `fzf` option (second below), with the symlink option (third) as a close second.  There's no reason you can't use both:

---

- *Option 1:  Reverse History Search*

  You can use the reverse history search in Bash (and other shells) to quickly repeat the `cd /mnt/...` command.

  Advantage:  No additional configuration required.

  First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the reverse history search.  You'll see:

  ```
  (reverse-i-search)`':
  ```

  Start typing `Doc` and Bash will find the most recent command with `Doc` in it.  If this *isn't* the `cd` command, then continue to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to cycle backward in the search results until you find it, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to repeat it.

---

- *Option 2:  Reverse history search with `fzf`*

  [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), the "command-line fuzzy finder" is a popular utility for "filtering lists".  In this case, the list is your shell command history.

  ```
  sudo apt install fzf
  source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/key-bindings.bash
  # Add the source line above to your ~/.bashrc for future use
  ```

  Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will now bring up a search/filter of your history.  Typing `cd Doc` will narrow down the list, likely to the exact `cd mnt/c/Users/nyck33/Documents` you want.  Simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to repeat it.

---

- *Option 3:  Symlink in your home directory*

  You can create a symlink in your Ubuntu home directory leading to your Windows home directory:

  ```
  ln -s /mnt/c/Users/nyck33/Documents/ ~/windocs
  ```

  With this in place, you can simply `cd ~/windocs/` to get to that location.  There is no need for any `~/.bashrc` modification since the symlink is simply permanently stored in your home directory.

---

- *Option 4:  A shell alias:*

  You can create a Bash (or other shell) aliases to easily move to that directory:

  ```
  alias windocs="cd '/mnt/c/Users/nyck33/Documents/'"
  ```

  Executing `windocs` as a command from Bash will then take you to that location.

  You can, of course, add the `alias` to your `~/.bashrc` to have it always available.

---

- *Option 5:  A shell variable*

  As mentioned in the comments, you can define your Windows Documents directory as a shell variable and then `cd` to it:

  ```
  windocs="mnt/c/Users/nyck33/Documents"
  cd $windocs
  ```

  The variable declaration can be made permanent by adding it to `~/.bashrc`